# How to increment a click amount by 1 every second

Tags: java, android

So I have been trying to figure out how to make the total amount of current clicks go up
by one every second. Say the amount of clicks is 0. Everytime I click it goes up by 20. But I also want it to go up by 1 every second. I have tried using time handler and I believe I have just been messing it up.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String KEY_COUNT = "count";
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate!");
        mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        int count = mPrefs.getInt(KEY_COUNT, 0);

        count = count + 1;
        Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
        editor.putInt(KEY_COUNT, count);
        editor.commit();

        mTextView = new TextView(this);
        setContentView(mTextView);
        mTextView.setTextSize(40);
        mTextView.setText("Count : " + count);
        Log.d(TAG, "Count is " + count);
        setContentView(mTextView);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTextView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }   

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //  SystemClock.sleep(2000);
        int clickCount = 20 + mPrefs.getInt("clicked", 0);
        mPrefs.edit().putInt("clicked", clickCount).putBoolean("user", true).commit();
        mTextView.setTextColor(0xff00ff00);
        mTextView.setText("The amount of times Lee Ji Eun has clicked:" + clickCount);
    }

}
```

Comment: `int clickCount = 20 + mPrefs.getInt("clicked", 0);` so its is going to increment by 20 what else do you expect?

Comment: Do you ask for 1. every second click count should increase by 1 and 2. if the user clicks the button it also increases by one. Maximum count can be 20. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: If i am not wrong you want your click to be counted after a second only and if any user click twice within a second then it should be counted as 1 click only

Answer (score 1):

So what you're basically trying to do is to increase the counter by 1 every second. Since this task should be repeated multiple times you can use a `TimerTask`.

#### Example

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Do whatever you wanna do right here (like increasing the clickCount)
            }
        });
    }
};
// scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 1000);
```

This task will be repeated as long as the activity isn't destroyed or `Timer.cancel()` gets called.

Answer (score 0):

On every click save your current time and match it with previous clicked time. If difference is equal to or greater then 1 seconds then count that click otherwise don't.